# Why isn't my Backbone Collection reset event firing?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript

I went through the Railscast tutorial and got it all working. Working on a quick prototype to see if Backbone is viable but I've messed something up and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I'm on Backbone 1.

View

```
class Shsh.Views.AssetsIndex extends Backbone.View

template: JST['assets/index']

initalize: ->
  @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template(assets: @collection))
  console.log('rendered')
  this
```

Router

```
class Shsh.Routers.Assets extends Backbone.Router
  routes: 
    '': 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Shsh.Collections.Assets()
    @collection.fetch({reset: true})

  index: ->
    view = new Shsh.Views.AssetsIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

The view gets rendered fine, but the length of @assets comes back as 0. I can go through the steps in the console and when I render the view again it comes back as being the correct length. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I also do actually have a collection and model. The code there is all boilerplate generated by Backbone On Rails.

Comment: In your view try `@listenTo @collection, 'reset', @render`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot. Initialize is spelt wrong in Shsh.Views.AssetsIndex.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fetch()` too early -- in router creation.  Should be called in specific route code instead.  The way you implemented it, fetch and reset may complete before route is triggered and therefore you'll start listening to `reset` after it has been fired

Comment: Moved it to the actual index function and it still doesn't work.